# Show values from database after button clicks

Tags: php, html

I have made a quiz that gets everything from the database, the question and the multiple choice answers. What i have at the moment, shows every question and answer on the page. The goal is to show each question after the previous one is answered.The answers the user can choose are inside buttons, so the goal is to show the next question in the database after an answer has been clicked. This is the code I use to grab the questions and answers from the sql database:

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "kinderboekenweek");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM vraag WHERE activiteit_id_activiteit = (SELECT id_activiteit FROM activiteit WHERE speurtocht_speurtocht_id= ".$activeSpeurtocht."  AND id_activiteit = ".$activiteit.") ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
      $i =0;
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo " Vraag: ". $row["vraag"].

         "<ul class = 'answers".$i."'.>
         </br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=".$row['optie1']." id='optie1".$i."'>  </br>".

         "</br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=". $row["optie2"]." id='optie2".$i."'> </br> ".

         "</br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=". $row["optie3"]." id='optie3".$i."'>  </br>".

         "</br> <input type='button' class='btn btn-default' name='Optie".$i."' value=". $row["optie4"]." id='optie4".$i."'>  </br>".

         "</br></br>
         </ul>";
         $i++;
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";

}
?>
```

Comment: @jothi Isn't the OP already using mysqli? 'mysqli_connect'

Comment: try to use mysqli  prepared statement to avoid sql injection